# Form FIller VB6 to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, vb6, vb6-migration

We are doing a conversion of a VB6 app to VB.NET. The old VB6 app had a control called FormFlow Filler, which is no longer supported (I believe its over 10 years old).

We have tried various third party controls to replace this but to no avail.

The control was used mainly for working with PDF's and when the user clicked on a PDF field this would trigger an event which would allow the user to select the data from another project. The selected data would then appear on the Field.

Comment: Looks like that company was bought by Adobe.  You should probably contact Adobe and see if they're still selling that control.  If they are (or are selling something equivalent) it probably has a .net port.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a library that fills in the pdf form without showing the document?

Comment: Nope, the user is the one that fills in the document by clicking on the field on the pdf. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. There is no control that can replicated this.